# Fill matrix cells in R by clicking and typing the content as in excel

Tags: r, matrix

Some time ago I found a function which allows to fill up a matrix by clicking in the single cells and then typing the content, as you would do in Excel.
I've been searching for hours without finding it, could someone please help me?
Many thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try data editor, for editing and entering data.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `dataentry` / `data.entry` function: http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/datasets/R/html/utils/html/dataentry.html

Comment: Or possibly: `mtx <- edit(mtx)`

Answer (score 1):

The `edit` function may succeed. The trick that needs to be learned is that it does not actually change the values but rather retruns an object with the cahnged values which you hte need to assign back to the original name if you want a durable effect:

```
mtx <- edit(mtx)  # displays this (may look different if not on a Mac.)
```

[image]

You would see the same window and get the cells to change in the window if you just used `edit(mtx)` but if you did not assign the changes back to 'mtx' they would be lost. If you also try `fix()` as suggested by @Abhilash you may see the behavior  that might be more "expected" by an Excel user. It's probably going to let you continue with expectations that are not really consistent with the design philosophy of R. Getting into the habit of always assigning values of function calls will let you reorient your thinking to "functional programming". The dataentry() function is a more low level function. You should look at all of these help pages:

```
 ?dataentry
 ?edit
 ?fix
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fix(variable)
```

Replace variable with the variable you want to edit. Hope this is what you were looking for.

**Note:** This replaces the original value and unlike edit command mentioned by @BondedDust doesn't return an object. Although fix uses edit and assigns it to the same variable.